# Page reloads when using href to change route in FlowRouter

Tags: reactjs, meteor, iron-router, flow-router

I'm using FlowRouter for routing in my Meteor+React app. I've defined some routes like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/about', {
    action: () => {
        mount(MasterLayout, {
            content: <AboutPage />,
        });
    },
});


FlowRouter.route('/terms', {
    action: () => {
        mount(MasterLayout, {
            content: <TermsPage />,
        });
    },
});
```

Now when I click on a link like `<a href="/about">About</>`, it reloads the entire page instead of just changing the content.

Also, if I use `FlowRouter.go('/about')`, it works fine and doesn't reload the page, only changing the content.

Please tell me what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one reason for this to happen, but this is what I have in mind:

It is because your `<a>` tag is possibly inside an element (parent or grandparent or grand-grand parent ... ) having a `click` event handler, and that handler calls to `.stopPropagation()`. This causes the event **stop bubbling up** to the **document click event handler**, added by FlowRouter, which is in charge of changing the route for you. Therefore the normal behaviour, when an `<a>` tag is clicked of browser, is executed which is to change the route and reload the page.

To fix this you could try to remove that `.stopPropagation()`. If you could not for some reasons, you could simply call `e.preventDefault()` and `FlowRouter.go` yourself.

If you are interested in how it works, here are some more information to dig into:

- To change the route without reload the page FlowRouter uses the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)
- In fact, FlowRouter does not use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) directly, but through an NPM module named [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)
- When initialize page.js is responsible for adding the [click event on document to alter the normal behaviour of clicking on an `<a>` tag](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/blob/aa605501e240727a0afaef7ec1641f60c8d7e8a5/index.js#L163)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. How can I check if `<a>` tag is inside a container that calls `.stopPropagation()`? Also, I was thinking of doing `e.preventDefault()` and `FlowRouter.go()` myself but I'll have to replace the `<a>` tag at every place. Would be better if I  go get `<a>` tag to work itself.

Comment: You are using React right? then you could write a component to wrap the normal `<a>` tag, this component will capture the click event on `<a>` tag and do the navigation job.

Comment: Found it!! [twbs:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) package was calling `.stopPropagation()`. Removing it did the trick. Will remove it permanently as I don't even use bootstrap that much. Thank you so much @Khang

Comment: My bad. It's still not working after commenting out the `.stopPropagation()` calls in the bootstrap package. @Khang

Comment: IMO, the best option is to write a component wrapping `<a>` tag and do the navigation